# C# grouped objects aren't being mutated as expected

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects, .net-6.0

I have a collection of objects entering a method as an `IEnumerable` of which I am grouping them by a reference property and then processing them group by group. The processing involves mutating the other properties of the objects. When the method completes and returns, the caller expects to have the collection of objects it passed in to be mutated. The whole process is asynchronous and the method looks like the following:

```cs
public async Task MutateMyObjects(IEnumerable<MyObjects> myObjects,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var myObjectsGroupedByGroupingEntity = myObjects
        .GroupBy(myObject => myObject.GroupingEntity);

    foreach (var myObjectGroup in myObjectsGroupedByGroupingEntity )
    {
        await ProcessGroup(myObjectGroup.Key, myObjectGroup, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Both `MyObject` and `GroupingEntity` are classes, as such my expectation is that `MyObject`s are passed as reference types and mutation is inherent through the process.

What actually happens is the caller of `MutateMyObjects` observes the same property values of `MyObject`s as it observed before the method call. These results are observed after the `Task` completes. While debugging the method above, observing the variable states before the method returns shows that the object collection under the variable `myObjectGroup` contain the mutated properties while the object collection under the variable `myObjects` does not.

I'm not sure what aspect of my understanding is missing causing me to get the wrong expectation, any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You cannot pass an object into an async function and wait for real-time processing - the async process will do "things", but it won't be by reference (and why would you assume that)?

Comment: What are you passing to the method?  If it's something like `someList.Select(x => new MyObjects(x))` then each time you iterated it will create new objects. You can pass it to the `MutateMyObjects` and it will mutate the objects it creates, but if you iterated the `IEnumerable` again it will create brand new unmutated objects.

Comment: Is the `IEnumerable<MyObjects>` perhaps hitting your database again for new data?

Comment: @riffnl Do you have a source for that last bit? [It works for me](https://rextester.com/DBKT69080).

Comment: @Llama that's after work's completed - that's not really what I meant - you can't use myObj into an async function and observe it's changes in the meantime it's working

Comment: @riffnl I see, I misunderstood your comment then.

Comment: @Llama looking back at my comment - I also know why sorry about that should have been a bit more verbatim about what I meant

Comment: @juharr Thanks to your question I looked at the source of the data which is a LINQ to SQL query piped into a mapper using Select. So I executed the query by adding a ToList() call after the mapping Select and now the object mutation persists because of what you described.

Comment: @tvandinther - You should only use `IEnumerable<T>` when you are expecting lazy evaluation. Otherwise use `List<>T` or `T[]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that I needed to execute the LINQ query first to materialise the objects before sending them off for mutation. What isn't shown in the question is how the `IEnumerable<MyObject> myObjects` is represented. In my case, `myObjects` was a deferred execution of a database fetch piped into an object mapping. This meant that when I mutated the objects, the `groupBy` forced the initialisation of the objects which were subsequently lost when the shown method returned. When the "mutated" objects were "used", the objects were in fact reinitialised.

As pointed out by @Enigmativity, in this method, the signature should probably be asking for `IList<MyObject>` to be sure of the existence of the objects as the method intends to mutate them. This means that the caller of the method is required to execute any LINQ queries before calling the method thereby avoiding this pitfall.

Comment: Or if you'd captured the mutated objects (returned them) - I personally think the GroupBy might have triggered the db query to run, it was captured temporarily but not returned. I guess if you'd stayed away from mutating and tended towards thinking in "immutable mode" then you probably would have returned it.. Good learning day though! 

Comment: Mutability and deferred execution can lead to issues.